# sqlalchemy query of timeseries data formatted as pairs of (step, next_step) time-adjacent samples

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, time-series

I have some time series data where I have sets of time series, each `Timeseries` instance of which has a one-to-many relationship
with `Point` instances. Below is a simplified representation of the data.

**tables.py:**

```
class Timeseries(Base):
    __tablename__ = "timeseries"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    points = relationship("Point", back_populates="ts")


class Point(Base):
    __tablename__ = "point"

    id = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    t = Column("t", Float)
    v = Column("v", Float)
    ts_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("timeseries.id"))
    ts = relationship("Timeseries", back_populates="points")
```

**Question**: I'm trying to come up with a query with these kind of columns: "timeseries_id", "id", "t",  "v", "id_next", "t_next", "v_next". That is, I want to be able to see each point's data alongside the next points data in the time series in chronological order, but I've been struggling get a table that doesn't elements from a implicit join? (Edit: An important point is that I want to be able to get this list using 100% queries and subquery objects in sqlalchemy, because I need to use this queried table in further joins, filters, etc.) Here's the basic start of what I got, (Note that I haven't run this code since this is a simplified version of my actual database, but it's the same idea):

```
# The point data actually in the database.
sq = (session.query(
    Timeseries.id.label("timeseries_id"),
    Point.id,
    Point.t,
    Point.v)
.select_from(
    join(Timeseries, Point, Timeseries.id==Point.ts_id))
.group_by('timeseries_id')
.subquery())

# first point manually added to each list in query
sq_first = (session.query(
    Timeseries.id.label("timeseries_id"),
    sa.literal_column("-1", Integer).label("id"), # Some unused Point.id value
    sa.literal_column(-math.inf, Float).label("t"),
    sa.literal_column(-math.inf, Float).label("v"))
.select_from(
    join(Timeseries, Point, Timeseries.id==Point.ts_id))
.subquery())

# last point manually added to each list in query.
sq_last = (session.query(
    Timeseries.id.label("timeseries_id"),
    sa.literal_column("-2", Integer).label("id"), # Another unused Point.id value
    sa.literal_column(math.inf, Float).label("t"),
    sa.literal_column(math.inf, Float).label("v"))
.select_from(
    join(Timeseries, Point, Timeseries.id==Point.ts_id))
.subquery())

# Append each timeseries in `sq` table with last point
sq_points_curr = session.query(sa.union_all(sq_first, sq)).subquery()
sq_points_next = session.query(sa.union_all(sq, sq_last)).subquery()
```

Assuming what I've done so far is useful, this is the part where I get stuck:

```
#I guess rename the columns in `sq_points_next` to append them by "_next"....
sq_points_next = (session.query(
    sq_points_curr.c.timeseries_id
    sq_points_curr.c.id.label("id_next"),
    sq_points_curr.c.t.label("t_next"),
    sq_points_curr.c.v.label("v_next"))
.subquery())

# ... and then perform a join along "timeseries_id" somehow to get the table I originally wanted...
sq_point_pairs = (session.query(
    Timeseries.id.label("timeseries_id")
    "id",
    "t",
    "v",
    "id_next",
    "t_next",
    "v_next"
).select_from(
    sq_points, sq_points_next, sq_points.timeseries_id==sq_points_next.timeseries_id)
)
```

I'm not even sure if this last would compile at this point since again it is adapted/simplified from real code but it doesn't yield a table of adjacent points in time, etc..

**Edit (August 10, 2019)**:

The following simplified query from Nathan is most certainly the right approach close to working, but raises errors for sqlite.

```
sq = session.query(
        Timeseries.id.label("timeseries_id"),
        Point.t.label("point_t"),
        func.lead(Point.t).over().label('point_after_t')
    ).select_from(
        join(Timeseries, Point, Timeseries.id == Point.ts_id)
    ).order_by(Timeseries.id)

print(sq.all())
```

Comment: Does the underlying database support window functions? It sounds like that's exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm using sqlite, and it looks like it does. I will look at this when I get a chance: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/

Comment: Ah, unfortunately window functions were only added to sqlite in version 3.25, and the version available in the default python distribution is 3.13. If you use Anaconda, though, you're in luck - it has version 3.26. Or if you're using windows it may be possible to access it - see the third comment on this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue34916.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get a recent enough version of the sqlite3 python module working (eg. by using Anaconda), you can use the `LEAD` window function to accomplish your goal. In order to use the results of the `LEAD` function in further queries, you'll need to use a CTE as well. The following approach worked for me with the schema you gave:

```py
sq = session.query(
        Timeseries.id.label("timeseries_id"),
        Point.id.label("point_id"),
        Point.t.label("point_t"),
        Point.v.label("point_v"),
        func.lead(Point.id).over().label('point_after_id'),
        func.lead(Point.v).over().label('point_after_v'),
        func.lead(Point.t).over().label('point_after_t')).select_from(
            join(Timeseries, Point, Timeseries.id == Point.ts_id)).order_by(Timeseries.id)

with_after = sq.cte()
session.execute(with_after.select().where(
        with_after.c.point_v < with_after.c.point_after_v)).fetchall()
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I'm not familiar with cte, but i will try this tonight. I am on linux so fingers crossed.

Comment: I haven't really checked it out yet if this answer works yet but enjoy the bounty lol.

Comment: Do feel free to follow up if you run into trouble :)

Comment: Hi Nathan, I'm getting an error for some reason, SQLITE doesn't seem to like the empty `over()` expression. I've updated the post with an incredibly simple query that fails.

Comment: Both my original query and the simplified one you posted work for me - in anaconda. As I mentioned in my post, the version of sqlite3 that's built into python by default doesn't support this kind of query. I'm afraid you'll need to either use anaconda or build your own python interpreter.

Comment: Ah okay I see now, this was just first time I was able to use your response. I'm using python 3.5.2 so I guess sqlite3 would be far out date. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than jumping through hoops to get the query to produce the paired results you are looking for, why not just retrieve all the `points` data related to a particular `Timeseries` row and then recombine the data into the pairs you are looking for?  For example:

```
from operator import attrgetter

def to_dict(a, b):
    # formats a pair of points rows into a dict object
    return {
        'timeseries_id': a.ts_id,
        'id': a.id, 't': a.t, 'v': a.v,
        'id_next': b.id, 't_next': b.t, 'v_next': b.v
    }      

def timeseries_pairs(session, ts_id):
        # queries the db for particular Timeseries row, and combines points pairs
        ts = session.query(Timeseries).\
            filter(Timeseries.id == ts_id).\
            first()

        ts.points.sort(key=attrgetter('t'))
        pairs = [to_dict(a, b) for a, b in zip(ts.points, ts.points[1:])]
        last = ts.points[-1]
        pairs.append({
            'timeseries_id': last.ts_id,
            'id': last.id, 't': last.t, 'v': last.v,
            'id_next': None, 't_next': None, 'v_next': None
            })

        return pairs

# pass the session and a timeseries id to return a list of points pairs
timeseries_pairs(session, 1)
```

Comment: So I suppose this does get a list of pairs, but I want to do this with just sub/query objects. I can manually construct a pair of points easily enough, but I want to use the query/table directly in further joins and filters, etc. (Also a small-ish detail: the timeseries instances are sorted by the `t` ("time") attribute, not id, which could be out of order. I'm not too worried about this though.).

Comment: @user27886 - fair enough. If I get some more time later, I will take a look at the query only approach. Edited the sort to use the `t` value just so it doesn't confuse anyone else that comes along.